# React post request to API does not show image that user has added to form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-post

I have created a back-end API using PostgreSQL and a front-end using React. I have created a form for the user to post a new review. The post request works but the image does not come through! screenshot of missing photo:
[image: screenshot of missing photo].

When I inspect the missing photo in Chrome dev tools, the web URL is there, it just doesn't show the image!

This is where the user inputs the image URL...

```
// inside form

<label>Photo URL:</label>
     <input
         type='url'
         value={newReviewPhoto}
         id='reviewPhoto'
         name='reviewPhoto'
         placeholder='photo URL'
         onChange={handlePhotoChange} />
<br />

// component to be rendered

 <img className='review-list-photo' src={singleReview.review_img_url} alt={singleReview.title} />


// inside html element in dev tools

<img class="review-list-photo" src="https://cdn1.parksmedia.wdprapps.disney.com/media/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/dbg002090SMALL.jpg" alt="k">
```

Anyone know why this is?

screenshot of posted review inside chrome dev tools:
[image: screenshot of posted review inside chrome dev tools]

Comment: where is the image component with this image url src? show that

Comment: It looks like the link is broken ie the URL isn't pointing to where it should be. What does the resulting img element look like?

Comment: @RobbieDenton I have attached a screenshot in the post

Comment: @RanuVijay the image url is any image url I add to the form

Comment: @KirstyRichmond I meant the html element, not the render.

Comment: Please show the code for the component that is supposed to display the image and an example url.

Comment: @ChrisG I've added a screenshot

Comment: @RobbieDenton I have added a screenshot

Comment: Please read [ask]. Don't post pictures of text. Do provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin sorry, I will edit the post.

Comment: Please can you show what the resulting img element looks like ie go to inspect > Elements and then find the img tag, then post that.

Comment: @RobbieDenton sorry I misunderstood your question. I have added it now

Comment: No probs, the img tag looks fine. I've copied it over to a code sandbox and it renders properly: https://codesandbox.io/s/render-img-5zngc

Can you upload your code to a sandbox as the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: @Bilbobaggins it is now working and I have no idea why! But thank you :D